Blender scripting, run the operator after the save window is closed?
have a problem with my addon.
I have a button that is intended to first save a copy of the file (a basic save copy window shows up) and then it runs some operations on the file's model etc. So basically it should save a copy before doing some procedures on the model. The problem is that when i press the button the dialog window pops up and then the code continues doing its business, so while i choose how to name the copy, it's already done with the modifications and then the final saved copy is a copy of CHANGED object, not original one.
I know i can delay all the procedures with a timer but i have no guarantee that user wont take longer to save a copy than i intended them to do.
Is there any way to add the logic so all the operations continue after the window is closed?
